# ¿cómo retornar datos de una base a mi web (con php)?

Tags: php, jquery, base-de-datos, sql, mariadb

Quiero aprender como hacer para que un usuario que entra a mi web inserte datos en mi base de datos y luego yo pueda retornarlos a la misma web. Algo asi como una caja de comentarios, donde el usuario envia sus datos a mi base y luego yo los retorno.
Ya aprendí lo primero..me falta lo segundo. ¿Alguien por favor podría decirme como retorno los datos que el usuario ya ingresó en mi base de datos (como los retorno a mi web)?

```
$my = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'MY') ;

$pro   =
  "INSERT INTO PEDIDOS (Nombre, Producto, Cantidad) VALUES ('Fernando', 'libro', 2)"
;

$ex = "SELECT * FROM PEDIDOS";

mysqli_query($MY, $ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pooof te falta mucho, recuerda que StackOverflow no es un sitio de enseñanza, si no de apoyo cuando estás atorado en un paso, (Previamente ya debes tener un código que hayas intentado) Te voy a dejar un código de ejemplo que te puede servir, al código le falta mucha estructura, validaciones, y control de errores, pero puedes empezar por aquí.

```
<?php 
$my = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'MY') ;
$pro   = "INSERT INTO PEDIDOS (Nombre, Producto, Cantidad) VALUES ('Fernando', 'libro', 2)";
$ex = "SELECT * FROM PEDIDOS";
$resultado = mysqli_query($my, $ex);
while( $fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ) ){
  echo 'Nombre: <b>'. $fila['Nombre'] .'</b><br>';
  echo 'Producto: <b>'. $fila['Producto'] .'</b><br>';
  echo 'Cantidad: <b>'. $fila['Cantidad'] .'</b><hr>';
}
?>
```

Reitero, SO no es un foro de enseñanza, la próxima vez, vente con un código que ya hayas intentado hacer.

Comment: ese código de arriba es mi código de intento.. ¿esa es la única forma de traer los datos, como array? Digo, o sea, porque quizá hay otra alternativa, algo más directo como simplemente imprimir.......Pero si no hay otra no importa..solo quiero saber...y gracias

Comment: Con una forma estilizada de hacerlo no, tienes que jugar con los datos, ahora que si no te importa el formato puedes hacer `var_dump( mysqli_query( $my, $ex ) )`

Comment: Es que yo decía porque no entiendo por qué es necesario el bucle.. O sea , pienso ¿no podían hacerlo más simple los creadores de php, es decir simplemente como imprimir sin necesidad de while y fetcharray?......pero en fin.. si no se puede hacer de una manera más limpia y directa, no importa, al final php nunca se ha caracterizado por ser el lenguaje más bonito de sintaxis....gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Ni siquiera Python te imprime de una forma limpia y sencilla, a esto le llamamos semántica de los lenguajes en este argot. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si resolvió tu duda.

Comment: donde marco????

Comment: Una pregunta más por favor: ¿POr que me da error el php cuando al while le coloco las llaves "}"? O sea, cuando están las llaves del while me tira un mensaje de error, pero cuando se las quito me muestra los datos de la base en mi html (como quería).......yo sabía que en php eran necesarias las llaves, o sea esto no es python.......no sé que habrá pasado